# Adding the SNS topic to python script to send email

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python script which in gives the IAM user names in AWS with their last login.I'm getting the expected result. now i have added the SNS topic to send the result via email.
But the response i had received in email is as below

Response:

```
User not logged into AWS: 

u

s

e

r

n

a

m

e

:
```

i need this in single line as Username: "*****"

```
PhysicalString =''
for user in resource.users.all():
    if user.password_last_used is not None:
        delta = (today - user.password_last_used.replace(tzinfo=None)).days
            final_result=("username: ", [user.user_name][0]," - ",delta , "days")
            physicalString = 'User not logged into AWS: \n\n' + '\n'.join(str(final_result))
            response = sns.publish(
            TopicArn='*************',
            Message= physicalString,
            Subject='IAM USER',
            )
            return final_result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
'\n'.join(str(final_result))
```

is saying "take each character in `final_result` and put a `\n` between them.

The problem is that `final_result` is being converted to a string, so the join is operating on each character rather than each element.

Try:

```
'\n'.join(final_result)
```

but you will need to convert `delta` to `str(delta)` before storing it in `final_result`.

Comment: i have modified the script  as below

Comment: I have modified the Physical string line as "physicalString = 'User not logged into AWS: \n\n' + ''.join(final_result)".  Now i got the expected output. @John thanks for the support.